# Comparing Query performance: Join Vs Select Distinct From Table

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, query-optimization, query-performance

I have two tables **person** and **city**. **person** table and **city** table are connected using city_id in person.  **person** table contains around a **million** rows and **city** table have around 10000 rows.

```
indexes on person: index1: id, index2: city_id
indexes on city:   index1: id
```

I need to select all those cities which do not have a person row associated with it.
city and person table are as follows (demo data).

```
CITY                PERSON

id  city            id  name   city_id
-------------       ------------------
1    city-1         1   name-1   1
2    city-2         2   name-2   2
3    city-3         3   name-3   2
4    city-4         4   name-4   3
5    city-5         5   name-5   1
6    city-6         6   name-6   3
7    city-7         7   name-7   4
8    city-8         8   name-8   8
```

I have written two queries to get the result:

query1:

```sql
     select c.id, c.city 
     from city c 
     left join person p on c.id = p.city_id  
     where p.id is null
```

query2:

```sql
     select * 
     from city 
     where id not in ( select distinct city_id from person)
```

execution plan of both the queries looks similar:

For query 1:
[image: mysq]
for query 2:
[image]

Then I used profiling and ran both queries a couple of times to see how much time are they taking:

```
query1: 0.000729 0.000737 0.000763
query2: 0.000857 0.000840 0.000852
```

Clearly from above data query1 outperforms query2.

I am confused as what I understand **query2** should outperform **query1**. Because query2's nested query is using city_id which is indexed and mysql can take advantage of **city_id index** to get all **id's** but query1 is using join which will take cartesian product of both tables.
Is it because I used less data f. **person(1000) and city(200) records**.

What am I missing due to which query1 is performing better than query2.

**Edit**

From mysql documentation:

```
covering index: An index that includes all the columns retrieved by a query. Instead of using 
the index values as pointers to find the full table rows, the query returns values 
from the index structure, saving disk I/O
```

This was the assumption which I made when I came up with query2.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN .. WHERE right_table.x is NULL` is optimized the same way as a `NOT EXISTS` subquery. Which means: The search for matching rows will stop as soon as one match has been found. That is documented (somewhere).

Comment: Be careful with `NOT IN (<subquery>)`. If the subquery may return NULLs, you can get an "unexpected" result.

Comment: With respect, your naive guesses about query performance are likely to be wrong. MySQL's on version 8. It's been under development for well over a decade, and has literally tens of thousands of programmer hours spent on optimization. The MySQL query planner has many optimization patterns built in to it. If it sees relevant ones, it uses the one it thinks is fastest, not the one you think is fastest.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks for replying. If suppose our query was to find all cities which have a person in that case query2 will perform better than query1? Because now query1 have to join both table.

Comment: @MohdWaseem - This is a different question. INNER and OUTER joins are optimized differently. The same applies for `IN (..)` and `NOT IN (...)` as well as for `EXISTS (..)` and `NOT EXISTS (..)` subqueries. An `IN (..)` subquery can be optimized to a *semijoin* as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/semijoins.html). However - The semijoin can also be written and optimized "by hand" and might perform even better. But that is too much for a comment. I'd even claim, that it's too much for an answer on SO.

Comment: The short answer to the question "Why is it faster?" is "Because it's optimized better". But if you want to know "Why is it optimized better?", you would need to take a deeper look into the documentation or even the source code. I can't say, that I fully understand it. So I can't give you **the** answer.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your performance differences are very small.  You really have to run queries multiple times to see if the differences are relevant.  The number of rows is quite small as well.  In all likelihood, all the data is on just one or two data pages.  So, you can't generalize from your example (even if the results are correct).

I would recommend writing this as:

```
select c.* 
from city c
where not exists (select 1 from person p where p.city_id = c.id);
```

And for performance, you want an index on `person(city_id)`.

This probably has the same execute plan as the `left join`.  I just find it a clearer statement of intent -- and it generally has very good performance on any database.

The `not in` is not exactly equivalent.  Here are some reasons:

1. The `select distinct` could throw off the optimizer.  It is not needed, but some databases might actually run a distinct.
2. `NULL`s are handled differently.  If *any* row in the subquery returns a `NULL` value, then *no rows at all* will be returned from the outer query.

Comment: I compared query that you mentioned with my queries. And Join query is performing best among the three. What if we want to query for all cities which have a person associated, For those cases join performance will not be better?

Comment: @MohdWaseem - Change `NOT EXISTS` to `EXISTS`.  These are a semi-join, which _should_ run as fast or faster than all the other options.  This is because it can stop after checking only one row in `person`.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if you want to discuss things further.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove distinct in NOT IN as IN() considers distinct records by itself. Somewhat join is more optimized here in your above query as there aint an extra select to retrieve data in join. But still that depends.

Joins are usually costly I would say.

Comment: We can expect a NOT EXISTS () & LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL to have the same query plan--(NOT) EXISTS is calculated by the same code as equivalent JOINs. Same as for NOT IN where using it is appropriate/equivalent. Which it isn't for certain cases involving NULL, and the question doesn't say there are no NULLs. See GrodonLinoff's answer.